# Email a text file as an attachment in perl with/without using Perl Modules

Tags: perl, email

I have a text file in my remote Linux machine. I want to email this file. Is there any simple way to write a code. Can we achieve this without using Perl Modules. Please suggest a simple code to do this.

```
        use MIME::Lite;
        $to = 'abcd@gmail.com';
        $cc = 'efgh@mail.com';
        $from = 'webmaster@yourdomain.com';
        $subject = 'Test Email';
        $message = 'This is test email sent by Perl Script';

        $msg = MIME::Lite->new(
             From     => $from,
             To       => $to,
             Cc       => $cc,
             Subject  => $subject,
             Type     => 'multipart/mixed'
             );


            $msg->attach(Type         => 'text',
         Data         => $message
        );


         $msg->attach(Type        => 'image/gif',
         Path        => '/tmp/logo.gif',
         Filename    => 'logo.gif',
         Disposition => 'attachment'
        );       
          $msg->send;
```

Here the attachment is there for gif file .Is "From" Mandatory ??? But how do i add a text file . I was not able to find a solution without using Perl modules

Comment: for those who have down voted this post, If u know the answer just give it . Otherwise just keep quiet . People come here to clarify their doubts and get answers. Dont discourage them.

Comment: Exactly, and that are the kind of people we do indeed want to come here. What we do not want are people who just want us to do their work for them. If you have any specific programming related question, please ask it. And if you have tried something to achieve your goal but got stuck, by all means, show us the problem and people will happily assist. But do not just post your requirements and treat us as your code monkeys. See http://stackoverflow.com/help for more information on what questions are on-topic and which are not.

Comment: I would think there's enough information in that example to work out how to attach a text file. You just change a couple of obvious things from the GIF example. And you really don't want to be thinking about doing this without a Perl module (but feel free to read the source of MIME::Lite!)

Comment: what should i write there for type : if its a text file Type => 'txt' ????

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be perl? Otherwise a really simple way is to use Mutt, which is pre-installed on many Linux distributions.

`$ mutt -s "Subject" -c "copy@mail.com" -a /tmp/attachedfile.txt "recipient@mail.com" < body.txt`

If it's part of a larger perl script, you can still make a system call to execute mutt from within the script.

`system("/usr/bin/mutt [...]") or die("Sending email failed: $?");`

Answer (score 0):

Many of the modules require that you have a Mail Transfer Agent on your machine, like sendmail. But I didn't have one, so I use [Mail::Sender](http://search.cpan.org/~jenda/Mail-Sender-0.8.22/Sender.pm). It has decent documentation, AUTH, supports attachments, and reports error messages.

Just make sure to set things like content-type correctly, and encoding. I am sending XLS files so the encoding was 'base64'.

Of course you also need an SMTP server account.

Comment: whats the encoding for text files ??

Comment: You can change the encoding of each part of a multipart message as you need.